# How can I append to a text file?

Tags: c++, c, file, handles

I have a program written in C++ which accepts text from a user and saves it to a text file using file handles.  Here are snippets of the program:

The program works fine.  The only problem with it is that it does not append the text to the text file.  Rather, it "removes" all the existing text and only saves the new text.

That is, the text saved in a previous session of the program is discarded and the new text is saved instead.  How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: Take into account that this code seems more c than c++. If you want to develop in strict C++, use fstreams to work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Include the `O_APPEND` flag when opening the file. See the reference page for [`_open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

As this is C++ consider using an [`ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) instead. These are type-safe and remove the requirement of having to specify the length of the arguments being written to the file:

```
std::ofstream out(full_path, std::ios_base::app);
if (out.is_open())
{
    out << "----Session----\n\n"
        << "Date/Time: " << datetime << "\n\n"
        << "Text: " << text << "\n\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your immediate answer :)