# How to append some text at the end of an existing text file

Tags: c++, file, text, append

If this is possible then any help would be great

I have already tried this code,

```
float deposit (float balance)
{


     double amount; 
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Enter the amount you wish to deposit"<<endl; 
    cin>>amount; 


    ofstream newBalance;                        
    newBalance.open ("deposit.txt", fstream::app);
    newBalance<<amount; 
    newBalance.close();

    balance = balance + amount; 
    writeBalance(balance); 
    return balance;  
}
//This is a function to allow the user to increase their balance
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append text to a text file in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393345/how-to-append-text-to-a-text-file-in-c) and [How can I append to a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13200079)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put

```
fstream::out | fstream::app
```

instead of just `fstream::app`

You can look at:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/

To put in a new line just do:

```
newBalance<<amount<<"\n";
```

Comment: But that doesn't change anything the next amount will still be right next to the previous

Comment: oh, I missed that you don't have <<"\n"  Sorry about that.

Comment: yh but that will only miss one line, I want it to miss a line over and over, not just for one time

Comment: So you go to the next line only the first time? You can't just modify a file as though it is an htmo textarea, just read it in, and write out the file making the change to the last line